# Unable to align slideshow box tried width and container any tips?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my slideshow "fadein" the same width as my footer and menu bar. I have tried messing with the css width, but it remains static. I put it also in a container where it should of stayed at 70%. Please give me any tips so that I can understand what I am doing  wrong? Thank You.

https://jsfiddle.net/zdc1s66L/

> html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title> Kontakt </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">           
   <h1 align="center">
   <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="A.Willi A.G" /></a>
</h1>    

<div class="menu_div">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
   <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Bewerber</a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="info.html">Info</a>
   <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
</div>  
</li>      
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Kunde</a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="personalverleih.html">Personalverleih</a>
   <a href="toolrental.html">Werkzeuge Mieten</a>
   <a href="referenzen.html">Referenzen</a>
   <a href="quali.html">Qulität, Sicherheit und Weiterbildung</a>
</li>
</div>
   <div class="fadein"> 
   <img src="welder1.png">
   <img src="welder1.png">
   <img src="welder1.png"> 
</div>
<div class="indexinfo"></div>
<div class="textinfo">
<p style="text-align:left;">
 Die <font color="#004b77"><b>A.Willi A.G</b></font> ist als Personalverleiher in der gesamten Schweiz und im Ausland erfolgreich tätig mit über 30-jährige Erfahrung in dieser Sparte. 
Wir haben uns spezialisiert auf die Vermittlung und den Verleih von qualifiziertem Fachkräfte für Rohr-Stahl-Gebäudetechnik.
Für die Beratung und Vermittlung sind in diesen Gebieten ausgewiesene Fachleute zuständig, welche als kompetente Partner mit unseren Kunden gemeinsam den Personaleinsatz planen.
In der A.Willi AG sind über 100 erfahrene Facharbeiter im Einsatz.
Unsere Personalberater haben in ihrem Vermittlungsbereich eine Fachausbildung und praktische Berufserfahrung sowie eine kaufmännische Weiterbildung. Als Spezialisten in ihrem Bereich erkennen sie schnell die Bedürfnisse unserer Kunden und vermitteln das entsprechend qualifizierte Fachpersonal. Sie sind die persönlichen Ansprechpartner während des gesamten Personaleinsatzes und garantieren durch regelmäßige Kontaktaufnahme eine optimale Anpassung an die Kundenbedürfnisse.
Das,Fachkräfte das wir unseren Kunden zur Verfügung stellen, wird von unseren Personalconsultants gezielt ausgewählt. Wir verfügen über einen festen Bestand an fachlich ausgezeichneten und zuverlässigen Mitarbeitern. Ihre Fachkompetenz halten wir durch berufliche Weiterbildung auf dem aktuellen Stand. Die Fachkräfte verfügen über Erfahrungen im Bereich der Chemie, Bio, Pharma- und Lebensmittelindustrie, Öl- und Gaspipelines, Fernheizung  und der Energieversorgung, Gebäudetechnik, Betriebsunterhaltung und Metallverarbeitung, Anlagen, Apparatebau, Stahlbau und Ausland Montage. 

Unsere Kunden schätzen die hohe Qualität unserer Dienstleistungen und die auf langfristigen Erfolg und faire Partnerschaft ausgerichtete Strategie. Wir sind stolz auf die gute Zusammenarbeit mit vielen langjährigen Kunden.
Unser Ziel ist quantitatives und qualitatives Wachstum. Unsere Dienstleistungen verbessern wir kontinuierlich, um unseren Kunden einen individuellen, zuverlässigen und schnellen Service zu bieten.

A. Willi AG= Personalberater= Fachkräfte= Kunden= Ziel
</p>
</div>

</ul>
<footer>
<div class="footer">
   <img class="footer-img" src="location_icon.png" width="25">
   <div class="info-text">
   <p><font color="#fff"> Wasgenring 94, CH-4055 Basel-Stadt</font></p>
</div>
   <img class="footer-img" src="mail_icon.png" width="25">
   <div class="info-text">
   <p><font color="#fff"> info@awilli-ag.ch</font></p>
</div>
   <img class="footer-img" src="icon_phone.png" width="25">
   <div class="info-text"> 
   <p><font color="#fff">t +41 (0)79 322 14 20</font></p>
</div>
   <a href="Zertifikat.html">
   <img class="footer-img" src="dossier_icon.png" width="25">
   </a>
   <div class="info-text">
   <p><font color="#fff">Zertifikate</font></p> 
</div>
</footer>
</body> 
</div>
</html>
```

> css

```
body { font-family: verdana; background:white ; color: black; }


.menu_div{background-color: #333; width:100%;}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}




li {
    float: left;
}



li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}



li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: black;
}



li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}




.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 100;
}



.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}



.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}



.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

        @keyframes fade {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        11.11%   { opacity: 1; }
        33.33%  { opacity: 1; }
        44.44%  { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0; }
}

    .fadein { position:absolute; height:400px; width:20px; outline: 1px solid blue; }
    .fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; opacity:0; animation-name: fade; animation-duration: 9s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
    .fadein img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s;  }
    .fadein img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 3s;  }
    .fadein img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 6s;  }



.menu_div { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 2.9em;
  margin-bottom: -0.4em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  z-index:1000;
  background-color: #333


}
.fadein { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3; 
  background: ;
  width: 10%;
  left: -0.5px;
  top: 0em;
  width: 90%;


  }

.fadein img{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    max-height: 400%;
}



.container {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}




.article {
    text-align: left;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom:11px
}




header {
background: white;color:black;
font-size: 0.9em;
}





}

.indexinfo {

padding:70px;
-webkit-flex: 1 100%;
flex: 1 110%;
height: 70px;
border: px solid black;
height: 200px:
text: center;

}



footer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 70px 1px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white
    {background-position: 5% 90%;}
}




.footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}





.footer-img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}




p {
  margin: 0;
}



textinfo {
width: 300px;
border: 25px solid green;
padding: 25px;
margin: 25px;

}
```

Comment: How are you trying to align it? Center? And just to clarify, are you referring to the `.fadein` element?

Comment: hey uncaught, yea correct mate, im trying to make it the same width as the menu and footer

Comment: Something like this then? https://jsfiddle.net/zdc1s66L/1/

Comment: thanks a ton mate, where did I mess up?

Comment: You had `width: 90%;` declared on your `.fadein` class, I reset this to `100%`, then changed the `outline` to `border` so that using it in combination with `box-sizing: border-box` I could ensure the element would remain within the constraints of the parent element. You might want to declare `width: 100%` on those nested images as well.